# Feelings icons that are not emoticons?

Tags: vector, icon, interface-design, conceptualization

For a particular project, I've got to come up with a set of a ten small one-color icons meant to represent certain feelings. However, these icons must not be emoticons, or faces, of people for that matter. While it doesn't sound like much, I find it to be way more difficult than I thought.

Here are the feelings and my ideas of icons to represent them:

1. Loving  || This one is obvious.
2. Angry || Lightning bolt
3. Surprised || Gift - wrapped up present?
4. Happy || Flower or sun
5. Scared || Spider?
6. Disgusted || No real idea. Poop?
7. Confident || Sunglasses?
8. Sad || Tears
9. Amused || No real idea.
10. Unimpressed || That's the toughest of them all. A tumbleweed might do the trick, but there's no way I could draw a recognizable one in 32x32px.

Any thoughts or ideas on the subject would be greatly appreciated! Advice on corresponding icons packs, if any, are also welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Were any of the answers helpful to you?

Answer (score 2):

1. Loving || Yup, obvious!
2. Angry || I would go with fire rather than lightning; when someone is angry or mad, they're "fired up", "hot under the collar", etc.
3. Surprised || I imagined a [Metal Gear Solid styled exclamation mark](http://www.gatheryourparty.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/mgs-pw-no4-670x379.jpg), but a gift or present would probably be friendlier!
4. Happy || Agree
5. Scared || A spider, a skull, a snake, or some of other similar connotation of death
6. Disgusted || I would suggest a cockroach - everyone knows what they are, and most of us can agree that they often live and survive in unpleasant environments, by unpleasant means. A poo might be a tad too literal for what you need, but by all means...!
7. Confident || Agree
8. Sad || Agree
9. Amused || What about one of those [theatrical happy/sad masks](https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/movie-video/512/Icon_32-128.png)? This is a tough one without going too literal.
10. Unimpressed || This one definitely implies boredom and lack of entertainment. Perhaps a 'zzz' icon or something like that, something that connotes sleepiness or lethargy?

Sorry if these aren't too helpful!

Answer (score 2):

- Surprised: a jack-in-the-box toy?
- Scared: a Halloween pumpkin? A bat? A ghost? Snaring teeth?
- Disgusted: a rotten fruit? Just a mushy looking fruit with "smell" coming out of it. Or a dirty sock?
- Confident: a rolled up diploma? A graduates beret? A judge's hammer?
- Sad: a fainted flower?
- Amused: a clown? (Mind you, they are scary for me)
- Unimpressed: agree with the sleepiness idea, although might imply boredom

Comment: +1 for such fantastic suggestions. If the icons are going on a humorous website then using a smiling clown for "amused" and clown with a mean face for "scared" would be hilarious. A lot of people are scared of clowns. Another idea for amused: hands clapping.

Answer (score 1):

1. Loving || Agree
2. Angry || A hissy cat?
3. Surprised || This one is the hardest for me to visualize, maybe just "BOO"?
4. Happy || Agree - maybe a sunflower! ;-)
5. Scared || A scorpion to gives a good impression of something that is scared and scares.
6. Disgusted || Roach or pile of trash with curl of stench/smoke.
7. Confident || Sunglasses or military hat.
8. Sad || Agree
9. Amused || I thought about a Joker Hat.
10. Unimpressed || Maybe two feet on a desk or tapping fingers?